# Splunk UF restart getting timedout using puppet code

Tags: linux, automation, configuration, puppet, splunk

I am getting a timedout error while executing /opt/splunkforwarder/bin/splunk restart command using puppet exec

```
class splunkforwarder::config(
    $deployment_server  = 'xxxxxx',
) inherits splunkforwarder::params {
  
    file { "${splunkforwarder::splunk_home}/etc/system/local/user-seed.conf":
      content  => template('splunkforwarder/user-seed.conf.erb'),
      notify   => Service[$splunkforwarder::params::service_name],
      mode     => '0600',
      owner    => 'root' ,
      group    => 'root',
    }

    exec { 'start_accept_license':
      path           => "${splunkforwarder::params::splunk_home}/bin",
      command        => "/usr/bin/sudo ${splunkforwarder::params::splunk_home}/bin/splunk start --accept-license --no-prompt",
      onlyif         => "/usr/bin/test -f ${splunkforwarder::params::splunk_home}/ftr",
      require        => Archive["/tmp/${splunkforwarder::params::install_file}"],
      before         => Exec['enable splunk at boot'],
    }

    exec { 'enable splunk at boot':
      path     => "${splunkforwarder::params::splunk_home}/bin",
      command  => "/usr/bin/sudo ${splunkforwarder::params::splunk_home}/bin/splunk enable boot-start -systemd-managed 0",
      creates  => $splunkforwarder::params::forwarder_service_file,
      require  => Exec['start_accept_license'],
    }
    
    exec { 'Restart splunk service':
      command   => "${splunkforwarder::params::splunk_home}/bin/splunk restart",
      path      => "${splunkforwarder::params::splunk_home}/bin",
      cwd       => "${splunkforwarder::params::splunk_home}/bin",
      creates   => "${splunkforwarder::params::splunk_home}/.splunk.restarted",
      require   => Exec['enable splunk at boot'],
    }
```

```
/opt/splunkforwarder/bin/splunk version
Splunk Universal Forwarder 9.0.0 (build 6818ac46f2ec)
```

I am using SUSE 12.3 server

I am trying to automate splunk forwarder installation using puppet which includes below steps

- Download package
- /opt/splunkforwarder/bin/splunk start --accept-license
- /opt/splunkforwarder/bin/splunk enable boot-start -systemd-managed 0
- /opt/splunkforwarder/bin/splunk set deploy-poll :8089

for which I have attached the screenshot of puppet code. when puppet agent runs, the code fails at restart Splunk step in the first go however when the puppet agent runs for the next time that stage gets successful

Comment: Please dont share code as Images, instead post the codesnippet as text.

Comment: How long does / should a Splunk restart actually take for this node?  Puppet `Exec`s have a default timeout of 5 minutes.  That can be changed if necessary, but if a restart is taking longer than expected then you should look into why that is.

Comment: The `creates` parameter for `.splunk.restarted` looks fishy.  Under what circumstances is this file created, and (especially) under what circumstances, if any, is it removed?